# How to connect my Android app to youtube

Tags: android, youtube

I'm currently developing an android app for my local club. I have set up a youtube channel that will show game highlights. I was wondering is there a way to connect my app to that it will connect to the youtube channel. I know i can connect via URL but is there any other way to do it more efficiently? 
Am new to this so any input will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, however there is an official Android Youtube player API, you can find more details at [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

Looking through the examples, having downloaded the library, and registered for an API key you simply enter the following code into your activity.

Firstly, ensure your activity extends the YouTubeBaseActivity class, and implements the OnInitializedListener. The resource for this activity should contain a YouTubePlayerView.

```
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlayVideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity 
    implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
```

Next, in the onCreate method add the code to initialise the player, for example.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);

    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)
        findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
}
```

Finally ensure that you override the onInitializationFailure, and onInitializationSuccess methods, examples below.

```
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "onInitializationFailure()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(video_id);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.